# How to add two columns from two tables in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have 3 tables: controller, allot_compnts and prev_allot_compnts, 3 tables have same fields, when i click on submit button, values in allot_compnts is copied to prev_allot_compnts and deletes from allot_compnts

Code :

```
  $id=@$_POST['submit']
  $type = isset($_POST['comp_type'])? $_POST['comp_type'] : '';
  $name = isset($_POST['comp_name'])? $_POST['comp_name'] :'';
  $comp = isset($_POST['num_comp'])? $_POST['num_comp'] :'';

 //Insert

 $sql1="INSERT INTO prev_alloted_comp(id,comp_type,comp_name,num_comp)
 SELECT comp_type,comp_name,num_comp FROM alloted_comp WHERE id='$id'" ;

 //Delete

 $sql2="delete from alloted_comp where id='$id'";

 //Here i'm trying to update controller table 

  if($type === 'Controller'){  

      $sql3= "UPDATE comp_controller SET 
      num_comp=(num_comp+$_POST[num_comp]) WHERE comp_name ='$name'
      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE num_comp=num_comp+'$_POST[num_comp]'";

      }
```

I'm trying to update num_comp in controller table based on $_POST[num_comp],but the value in controller table not updating

I'm new to this, please any one help me how to do this

**Update:** i just updated my code to

```
$id=@$_POST['submit']
  $type = isset($_POST['comp_type']);
  $name = isset($_POST['comp_name']);
  $comp = isset($_POST['num_comp']);

 //Insert

 $sql1="INSERT INTO prev_alloted_comp(id,comp_type,comp_name,num_comp)
 SELECT comp_type,comp_name,num_comp FROM alloted_comp WHERE id='$id'" ;

 //Delete

 $sql2="delete from alloted_comp where id='$id'";

 //Here i'm trying to update controller table 

  if($type === 'Controller'){  

      $sql3= "UPDATE comp_controller SET 
      num_comp=(num_comp+$_POST[num_comp]) WHERE comp_name ='$name'";

      }
```

Sill not working

Comment: Invalid syntax `(num_comp+$_POST[num_comp])`, properly escape strings, variables

Comment: @Thamilan That actually gets parsed and replaced by the according value in `$_POST`. Although it's still an open invitation to sql injection ofcourse. (With a bunch of E_NOTICE for using an undefined constant, but php is considering it as a string at that point)

Comment: @Thamilan, Thank you for commenting , i just want to add post value, is there any to modify this  '(num_comp+$_POST[num_comp])'

Comment: Also: I doubt `UPDATE ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` is valid SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$sql` variable with `$_POST['num_comp'] = 123` is parsed as `UPDATE comp_controller SET num_comp=(num_comp+123) WHERE comp_name ='Some name' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE num_comp=num_comp+'123'`

Possible errors

1. `isset($_POST['num_comp'])? $_POST['num_comp'] :'';`

You empty the value num_comp, if num_comp is not sent in the POST request. This will automatically lead to `SET num_comp=(num_comp+)` which is no longer a valid SQL statement.

2. `num_comp=num_comp+'$_POST[num_comp]'`

Is parsed as `num_comp=num_comp+'123'`. You try to add a string to a number.

3. `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

As far as I know `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is only valid with the [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) statement.